# Estou buscando um código para subsituir NAs pelo menor valor de um conjunto de dados usando replace

Tags: loop, dataframe, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-html, replace

Estou usando o código abaixo para subsituir NAs.
Meu objetivo é para cada pessoa, substituir os NAs da coluna ‘num’ pelo menor valor da própria coluna ‘num’. Eu não busco por função que necessitem da instalação de pacotes. Meu objetivo seria usar a função ‘replace’ ou outra similar.
Para isso estou usando a função ‘length’ para especificar o tamanho de acordo com a coluna pessoa.
Estou usando a função ‘replace’ para substituir o valor NA e usando a função ‘min’ para retornar o valor mínimo da coluna ‘num’.

```
for (i in 1:length(pessoa))

    {
      
    df$num <- replace (df$num, df$num == "NA", min(df$num [ which (df$pessoa [i] ) ] ) ) 
     
    }
```

O resultado esperado para o conjunto de dados abaixo seria o seguinte. Para JOAO os NAs deveriam ser substituídos por -1, enquanto para MARIA seria substituídos por 0.

```
df <- data.frame(

  pessoa=c("JOAO", "MARIA"),

  num=c(NA, NA, -1, 0, 5 ,9 ,NA ,NA ,2 ,3)

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criando data frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  pessoa=c("JOAO", "MARIA"),
  num=c(NA, NA, -1, 0, 5 ,9 ,NA ,NA ,2 ,3)
)
```

pessoa únicas (joão e maria)

```
pessoas <- unique(df$pessoa)
```

For para cada pessoa

```
for (pessoa in pessoas) {
  # é computado o mínimo da pessoa atual
  min_num <- min(df$num[df$pessoa==pessoa], na.rm=TRUE)
  
  # Aqui é verificado se o valor é NA e caso for, é alterado pelo valor minimo da pessoa
  df$num[df$pessoa==pessoa & is.na(df$num)] <- min_num
}
```

mostrando data frame

```
print(df)
```

|  | pessoa | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOAO | -1 |
| 2 | MARIA | 0 |
| 3 | JOAO | -1 |
| 4 | MARIA | 0 |
| 5 | JOAO | 5 |
| 6 | MARIA | 9 |
| 7 | JOAO | -1 |
| 8 | MARIA | 0 |
| 9 | JOAO | 2 |
| 10 | MARIA | 3 |